# Rust windows api and cross-platform building?

Tags: windows, rust, compilation, cross-platform

I have a program which needs access to the Windows API if run on Windows, and Linux's `libsecret` if on Linux.

Currently I'm using the `windows` crate to implement functionality specific to windows.

Is there a method to make it so that the Windows API functionality can be compiled on a Linux build box? I don't want to rely on the `windows` crate to build for Windows. I want anyone to be able to build the software, and I want it to work on Windows. What solutions support this?

I would prefer not to use feature flags for this. I want the same executable to work on all platforms if possible.

Comment: *"I want the same executable to work on all platforms if possible"* - that's not going to be possible; an ELF (linux executable) is fundamentally different than an EXE (windows executable). Unless you just mean the same source.

Comment: Are you looking for *platform-specific dependencies*? See [How to have different dependencies depending on OS family](/q/29854912/2189130) (i.e. builds for Windows targets would use `windows` crate, builds for Linux would use the `libsecret` crate). Or do you actually want cross-compiling? (i.e. build Windows EXE on Linux)

Answer (score 0):

Rust has the `cfg` macro for only including code depending on the OS and many other related conditions. In depth reading here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html

Short example (taken from that link ^)

```
#[cfg(target_os = "linux")]
fn linux_only() {
  // do linux stuff
}
```